# How to extend functionality in D?

Tags: d

Consider this code:

```
template isSend(T){
    import std.meta;
    import std.traits;
    alias fieldNames = FieldNameTuple!T;
    static if(fieldNames.length == 1 && fieldNames[0] == ""){
        enum isSend = true;
    }
    else{
        alias toType(string s) = typeof(__traits(getMember, T, s));
        enum isSend = allSatisfy!(.isSend, staticMap!(toType, fieldNames));
    }
}
```

It is super hacky, but what it basically does is to mark specific types as `sendable`. If the type has no members it is considered sendable by default. It is also considered `sendable` if all members are `sendable`.

```
struct Foo{}

// sendable because all members are sendable
struct Bar{
    int i;
}

// not sendable because we set it explicitly to false
struct Baz{}
enum isSend(T: Baz) = false;

// sendable because Bar is sendable
struct Test1{
    Bar bar;
}

//not sendable because Baz is not sendable
struct Test2{
    Baz baz;
}
```

This works fine because everything is in the same module, but it breaks down once I try to implement `isSend` for another type outside of the module where `isSend` is defined.

The example is pretty simple and I could possible have used `UDA's` to implement it.

Another example would be

```
auto arr = iota(0, 100).array;
```

This is defined in phobos and creates an array, but it would be a bit awkward if every data structure would have to define its own function. Consider something like this

```
int[] arr = iota(0, 100).collect!(int[]);
Array!int arr1 = iota(0, 100).collect!(Array!int);
```

How could this be achieved?

```
auto collect(Iter, T)(ref Iter iter){...}
auto collect(Iter, A, T: Array!A)(ref Iter iter){...}
```

I think the problem is that `collect` accross different modules will be different, is there a way to say that I want to create an overload/specialization for `collect` in module a for module b?

What other alternatives do I have to extend functionality?

**Update:**

Basically this is what I want to implement

```
int[] arr = iota(0, 100).collect!(int[]);
Array!int arr1 = iota(0, 100).collect!(Array!int);
....
```

Imagine that `collect` would have been defined in some library. Now I have another container, let us call it `List`. I want to be able to call collect on a `List!T`

```
List!int arr2 = iota(0, 100).collect!(List!int);
```

But `collect` doesn't work with `List` because `List` is from another library. Now I need to extend the functionality of `collect` to also work with a `List!T`.

**Can `collect` be expressed in D?**

I tried to implement it with template specialization and I am not sure if that is the right tool.

```
T collect(T, Range)(auto ref Range range){
    static assert(false, "Collect is not implemented for " ~ T.stringof);
}

T collect(A, T: Array!A, Range)(auto ref Range range)
    if(isInputRange!Range){
    auto arr = Array!A();

    foreach(ref e; range){
        arr.insert(e);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Now it can be used like this

```
Array!int arr = iota(0, 100).collect!(int, Array!int)(); //ugly
```

Rust offers this functionality with [collect](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect).

Comment: I really don't understand the question, but if you just want to overload a `collect` function from two different modules, you can do `alias collect = modulea.collect; alias collect = module.collect;` and then they are combined.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe I updated my question, I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: `collect` could just be written with `auto arr = T!A();` and not need to be specialized at all... if you're writing it yourself anyway, just write it generically the first time and skip all the specializations. `auto collect(alias A)(auto ref Range range) { auto arr = A!(ElementType!Range)(); foreach(ref e; range) { arr.insert(e); return arr; }` As long as the container has an `insert` method, you can call that with `whatever.collect!Array` or `whatever.collect!List` and so on. Otherwise, you could still do the overloading alias thing.

Comment: Rust's `collect` seems to be the same as D's [std.array.array](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#array). Maybe more general because it infers the type of the collection to use? It is still used in the same places.

Comment: If this question is about "extending", then D's [UFCS](https://dlang.org/spec/function.html#pseudo-member) should solve this. If this is about getting `isSend` to work, it might be a problem about types not being accessible. Please, give a failing example.